# How can minicom "permanently" translate incoming newline (\n) to CR+LF?

Tags: serial-port, newlines, minicom

I have a micro-controller device that is sending newline-terminated strings through the USB-attached serial port and (so far) I'm using `minicom` version 2.6 to read from `/dev/ttyACM0`. I've setup the terminal application for line wrapping but I'd like it to go to the beginning of the next line when receiving a line feed character from my serial device. Can [and how does] `minicom` do that?

**EDIT**: I've also tried ways known by me such as `stty /dev/ttyACM0 ...,inlcr` and `screen /dev/ttyACM0 ...,inlcr`, which I know have options to translate incoming new-line into carriage-return+line-feed (CR+LF) and none of these work either. I've tried other options as well (such as `ocrnl`, in case my logic was wrong, `nl` and `-nl`), none work and I don't know why.

Ah, and I'm running Manjaro 16.06-rc1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Took me long enough but here I am at last! I've had to download minicom source code to get an idea what to do to avoid the hassle of constantly pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd>... Here it is.

`minicom` stores its parameters in a configuration file, which defaults to `$HOME/.minirc.dfl`. Put the following line, *to the letter*:

```
pu addcarreturn    Yes
```

and now `minicom` adds a carriage return to all incoming lines. I have no idea why it didn't save that option along with its configuration file in the first place but, heck, I don't care now!

Beware that every option after `pu` must take **exactly 16** characters, padded with spaces to the right.

Comment: NOTE: when running _root_ (which i had to do to have access to the usb port),  .dfl is located at ```/etc/minicom/minirc.dfl```

Answer (score 7):

**ANSWER:**
In *minicom* press `Ctrl+A Z`. This will show the menu. Then press `U` ("Add Carriage Ret"), and *minicom* will add the `CR` symbol to each `LF` symbol automatically.

You may want to do that again in order to turn this function OFF.

**WORKAROUND:**
Try sending the lines terminating with `"\r\n"` from the microcontroller.
`\r` means the *Carriage return* (ASCII code 13 or 0xd)
`\n` means the *Line feed* or *New line* (ASCII code 10 or 0xa)

Comment: So I get the answer is «*No, it doesn't*», right?

Comment: @Nasha I have never tried to do that. I just hit the very similar problem and solved it the way I described. So it was not be the answer to your actual question, but rather a work-around suggestion. Please see my edited answer for Minicom v.2.7.

Comment: Ok, it seems to work now. Is there a command line argument to avoid doing it all the time interactively?

Comment: You can execute `minicom -s` as root, choose `Screen and keyboard`, then press `T - Add carriage return`, and `Save setup as dfl` to turn this option ON systemwide. Or you can save this configuration in a separate onfig-file, and then use as `minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB0 /etc/minicom/minirc.myconfig`. Unfortunately, Minicom 2.7 release seems to include an old man page, so these new options are not described there.

Comment: Saving the `add carriage return` option in the configuration file doesn't seem to work. I *must* go through the setup screens and manually tell minicom to add the carriage return (i.e. `Ctrl`+`Z` then `U`)... Oddly enough when I go to the menu (`Ctrl`+`Z`), select configure minicom (`O`) and then configure the display & keyboard, the option `Add carriage return` is set to `No`! Go figure!